# Don't understand behaviour of List<Func<int, int>> in for-loop

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, lambda, func

I've just started getting into Lambda-Expressions, and found a behaviour that - to me - seems unintuitive. I suspect I haven't understood aspects of the underlying concept.

so we have These two for-loops:

List< Func< int, int>> list = new List< Func < int, int>>();

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    list.Add(j => j + i);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(list[i](i));
  }
```

I had expected an Output something like this:

0 ( since j+0 with j=0 equals 0)

2 ( since j+1 with j=1 equals 2)

4 (…)

6

8

Instead the Output showed:

5 ( I suspect since j+5 with j=0 equals 5)

6 ( I suspect since j+5 with j=1 equals 6)

7 (…)

8

9

What happens is that adding Funcs to the List the i-value is updated for every previously-added Func.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 3):

That is because the local variable `i` is only capturing the last value. You should create a separate variable with a local scope (one that goes out of scope for the next iteration):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int l = i;
    list.Add(j => j + l);
}
```

Comment: That I understand, but why is that so? I never knew that the incremented local variable i affected the other Func-elements of list. Why isn't it static - it's not a Parameter of the func-element after all!?

Comment: Because of the scope of the variable.

Comment: @TheSlazzer Yes, it is a parameter.

Comment: I see now, it is a Parameter because of capture. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very written about Capture/Closure issue

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   var newI = i;
   list.Add(j => j + newI);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(list[i](i));
}
```

**Output**

```
0
2
4
6
8
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known effect of *capture*; in your current code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    // each lambda uses shared "i" variable
    list.Add(j => j + i);
}

// Now (after the for loop) i == 5, 
// that's why all lambdas j => j + i are in fact j => j + 5
```

If you want to *avoid* `i` variable capture, you can change your code into

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    // local variable: each iteration has its own temp to be captured
    int temp = i;

    list.Add(j => j + temp);
}

//  1st lambda j => j + temp equals to j => j + 0
//  2nd lambda j => j + temp equals to j => j + 1
// ...
// n-th lambda j => j + temp equals to j => j + n - 1
```

Comment: I got what happened (j+5) but wanted to know how that came About. I see now it's because of capture, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When a local variable is captured, it is captured by reference, so any update to the variable will be reflected when you use the captured variable in the function.

The compiler lifts the local variable as the field of a generated class, basically what happens is something similar to this:

```
class Closure
{
    public int i;
    public int Fn(int j) => i + j;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Func<int, int>> list = new List<Func<int, int>>();
    var c = new Closure();
    for (c.i = 0; c.i < 5; c.i++)
    {
        list.Add(c.Fn);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(list[i](i));
    }
}
```

You can get around this behavior by declaring a local variable in the loops o the compiler will capture that local variable, and since the semantics of that are that the variable must be different on each loop iteration, the compiler will generate a separate capture instance for each iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int l = i;
    list.Add(j => j + l);
}
// Equivalent to :

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var c = new Closure();
    c.i = i;
    list.Add(c.Fn);
}
```